# Check write ops for a method

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In Google App Engine, is there any way to get the amount of write ops used when a particular method is executed? I'm using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html) will give you the number of RPC calls, and you can use the [following table](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html) to map API call to low level datastore operations.

Comment: The SDK also gives a nice breakout of how many write ops a entity required. This can be useful for making sure you don't forget to account for index writes, etc....

Comment: @RobertKluin What gives a nive breakdown? The SDK docs? Or some functionality in the SDK? Or just a general inspection of the code in the SDK?

Comment: @MarkSilberbauer Goto the SDK datastore viewer, there is a column called "Write Ops" that gives you a count of how many actual write operations a particular entity took.  This number can be quite large if you've not been diligent about *not* indexing properties.  This in addition to proppy's Appstats suggestion will really help optimize an app.